# lowlatency kernel in 17.10 put machine in unusable state

Tags: grub2, system-installation, kernel, 17.10

The lowlatency kernel that came from my 17.04->17.10 upgrade put my machine in unusable state.  (This new kernel variety is not mentioned in 17.10 release notes.)  Entering grub, starting with generic kernel, and then completely removing

linux-image-4.13.0-16-lowlatency

(using synaptic) fixed my problem.

My question is basically:  What is going on?  How do I make my machine work with a lowlatency kernel?

Comment: The low latency kernel can be unstable as it sacrifices stability for speed. It is questionable if it is even needed - https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration#the_kernel "Kernels >= 2.6.31 seem to work pretty well without RT patch, also for real-time pro audio usage. It's not strictly necessary anymore to install a real-time ('rt') kernel to get good results. Although the best results are still expected when using a real-time kernel. Try it, test it and decide for yourself."

Comment: Use a non-low latency kernel and file a bug report from wherever you got the kernel.

Comment: If you install fresh Ubuntu 17.10 you get `generic` kernel instead. I've upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 initially and also ended up with `lowlatency`, after switching kernel to generic, failed with the GNOME starting. Decided to give up and installed fresh 17.10. Problems were gone.

Comment: I have the same experience. I have been using the lowlatency series of kernels for years over many releases without issues. But with Artsy I get sluggish mouse movements and keyboard missing key hits.

Comment: If you file a bug report, please paste a link here. I will participate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty much just guessing here, but it's possible that your system can only boot when certain kernel modules are loaded that are not supplied with the kernel. Then they have to be built using `dkms`, but this only works if you have the corresponding `linux-headers-4.13.0-16-lowlatency` package installed. When you install that package, the appropriate kernel modules will automatically be built for you.

In general the headers package should always be installed when an image is installed, but for some reason this does not always automatically happen.

Comment: I just hit the same exact problem; 17.04 to 17.10 automatic update installed the lowlatency kernel but not the headers. Left my system broken because it was running the closed NVidia drivers, which silently (without error) failed to install correctly due to the missing headers - they noted the lack, but didn't seem to consider it a breaking problem.
(Lord help me, I miss `emerge @module-rebuild`...)

Comment: Maybe related to [bug 1728760](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aufs-tools/+bug/1728760)?