# Slow mouse on 17.10

Tags: mouse, 17.10

I have a Razer DeathAdder which has been working great until I upgraded to 17.10. Now the mouse moves incredibly slowly. As in, to get from the left side of my 4k monitor to the right side, I'd have to scroll my mouse across the mouse pad maybe 30 times?

Everything was fine in previous releases, so something changed with 17.10. I tried going into the mouse properties in settings but changing the mouse speed there has absolutely zero effect.

Right now, I have a script that I run to modify the transform matrix, but I have to run it every time I turn my screen on, I guess because my mouse is plugged into the hub on the back of my monitor? It's also silly that it won't save my settings across reboots, etc.

Here are my current settings. What should I play with to change the mouse speed, and how do I get the settings to be permanent? Unfortunately, other DeathAdder mice are supported by openrazer/polychromatic, but apparently not my "black edition" that I specifically purchased because it doesn't have LEDs all over the place.

```
$ xinput --list-props 12
Device 'Razer Razer DeathAdder':
Device Enabled (153):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed (386): -0.413043
libinput Accel Speed Default (387): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (388):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (389):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (390):   1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (287):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (288):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (391): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (392): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (393):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (394):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (395):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (396): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (397): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (398):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (399):    0
Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event2"
Device Product ID (276):    5426, 41
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (289):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (290):   1
```

Comment: Did you bother looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/966651/mouse-lagging-on-ubuntu-17-10 and/or  https://askubuntu.com/questions/966954/ubuntu-17-10-tons-of-lags-with-mouse-and-window-glitch?

Comment: Neither of those are useful or even related to my problem. My mouse isn't "glitchy" -- it's just extremely unresponsive. The sensitivity level needs to be boosted and I need to know how to permanently persist those changes. I'm also already using gnome on Xorg and _not_ Wayland because I have an nvidia card and Wayland doesn't support nvidia at all.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded my Notebook, because 17.04 no longer gets updates, and had the same problem. Afer some fiddling around I found a solution, altough late to your question, but it maybe help someone in the future. 
So here we go:

First install `gnome-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then I'd recommend turning down the mouse speed to half or else it will be super fast after the next step (not completely slow cause then it wont move). In the Tweak-Tool change the Acceleration Profile to Flat. Now you can adjust the speed in the system settings to fit your needs.

I hope that helps (at least it did for me).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: switching from 4.13.0-16-lowlatency (default) to 4.13.0-16-generic solved my input lag problems.

I've had a similar problem when I switched from ubuntu-gnome 17.04 to ubuntu 17.10. My mouse became unresponsively slow and later on, my keyboard became unresponsively slow as well. While trying (and failing) to backup /home directory to an external drive, I ran iotop and I noticed that ksoftirqd was constantly at 99.99% IO and every few seconds other irq processes were at 99.99% as well, according to the internet that means something in my PC is interrupting the CPU faster then it can handle. In a last ditch effort before having to reinstall ubuntu-gnome 17.04, I rebooted and in the grub menu I selected the "normal" 4.13 kernel (the 4.13-lowlatency kernel being the default). I'm now using kernel 4.13.0-16-generic and I'm finally able to use the system again.

Not sure if you have the same situation, but it might be worth a try to switch to 4.13.0-16-generic instead of 4.13.0-16-lowlatency

Comment: OP isn't using lowlatency kernels.

Comment: @MichaelBay: how do you know? For some reason the update from 17.04 to 17.10 automagically switched to the lowlatency kernel in my case so that could very well be the cause. I for sure will try switching the the generic kernel as well and report back the results.

Comment: @Forage It didn't. Either you have Ubuntu Studio or similar -or- you installed some lowlatency kernel at some point (or some software requiring it installed that for you).

Comment: @MichaelBay I did not (knowingly) install the lowlatency kernel. I had upgraded van ubuntu-gnome (official gnome remix) 17.04 to ubuntu 17.10. I dont know what would trigger the lowlatency kernel to be installed.

Comment: @Pieter AFAIK the only Ubuntu flavor using lowlatency by default is Ubuntu Studio. It may have been installed because some software depends or prefers it. Additional info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126664/why-choose-a-low-latency-kernel-over-a-generic-or-realtime-one and the ONLY mention to such kernels in Ubuntu (STUDIO) community document: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel

Comment: @MichaelBay, I also have a laptop (the one I'm writing this on right now) which is running a low-latency kernel (4.13.0-16-lowlatency #19-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT). I have never installed Ubuntu Studio on it.  This laptop also had Ubuntu-Gnome installed (17.04) which I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10. When I do a 'dpkg -l | grep linux-image' I can see the previous kernels fro Ubuntu-gnome 17.04, non of which are low-latency kernels. The only low-latency kernel is the 4.13.0 kernel that was installed with the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Judging from questions like (https://askubuntu.com/questions/968343/lowlatency-kernel-in-17-10-put-machine-in-unusable-state) I @Forage and me we not the only once that got the low-latency kernel installed with the upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10

Comment: Yes, I see it now and it has been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aufs-tools/+bug/1728760

Comment: I can confirm that getting rid of the lowlatency kernel solved the problem with the slow mouse, in addition to some other issues where the system became unresponsive

Comment: I'm a little slow to respond here, but I can confirm I am *not* using a lowlatency kernel. I'm currently on 4.13.0-36-generic